# Predict function of neuralnet gives odd results

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am relatively new to both machine learning techniques and programming in R, and at the moment I am trying to fit a neural network to some data that I have. However, the resulting predictions of the neural network do not make sense to me. I have looked through StackOverflow but could not find a solution to this problem.

**My data** (this is a part of the test set, the training set is of the same format)

```
    target monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday  indepedent
428    277      1       0         0        0      0        0        3317
429    204      0       1         0        0      0        0        1942
430    309      0       0         1        0      0        0        2346
431    487      0       0         0        1      0        0        2394
432    289      0       0         0        0      1        0        2023
433    411      0       0         0        0      0        1        1886
434    182      0       0         0        0      0        0        1750
435    296      1       0         0        0      0        0        1749
436    212      0       1         0        0      0        0        1810
437    308      0       0         1        0      0        0        2021
438    378      0       0         0        1      0        0        2494
439    329      0       0         0        0      1        0        2110
440    349      0       0         0        0      0        1        1933
```

**My code**

```
resultsnn <- neuralnet(target~monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday+saturday+independent,data=training,hidden=3,threshold=0.01,linear.output = TRUE)
compute(resultsnn,test[,2:8])$net.result
```

**My results** (the predicted value is the same for ALL test set cases)

```
           [,1]
428 508.4962231
429 508.4962231
430 508.4962231
431 508.4962231
432 508.4962231
433 508.4962231
434 508.4962231
435 508.4962231
436 508.4962231
437 508.4962231
438 508.4962231
439 508.4962231
440 508.4962231
```

**What else have I tried?**

I have tried versions without the dummies (only including the independent variable, this does not change the type of results)

I have created some synthetic data and used this as an input, for the same code, this does work properly:

```
#building training set
input_train <- as.data.frame(c(1:100))
output_train <- as.data.frame(c(sqrt((1:100)+1)))

train <- cbind.data.frame(output_train,input_train)
colnames(train) <- c("output","input")

#building test set
input_test <- as.data.frame(c(101:150))
output_test <- as.data.frame(c(sqrt((101:150)+1)))

test <- cbind.data.frame(output_test,input_test)
colnames(test) <- c("output","input")

#NEURALNET PACKAGE
#neural network 3 neurons
res.train <- neuralnet(output~input,data=train,hidden=3,threshold=0.01) #train nn
compute(res.train,test[,2])$net.result #predict using nn on test set
```

I have also tried other packages (e.g., *nnet* and *RSNNS*), but these packages already fail to provide correct predictions when using the synthetic data.

**Some additional information**

Some additional information on the data types:

```
str(test)
 'data.frame':  82 obs. of  8 variables:
  $ target     : int  277 204 309 487 289 411 182 296 212 308 ...
  $ monday     : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  $ tuesday    : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  $ wednesday  : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  $ thursday   : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ friday     : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ saturday   : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ independent: int  3317 1942 2346 2394 2023 1886 1750 1749 1810 2021 ...

str(training)
 'data.frame':  397 obs. of  8 variables:
  $ target     : int  1079 1164 1069 1038 629 412 873 790 904 898 ...
  $ monday     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  $ tuesday    : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  $ wednesday  : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  $ thursday   : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  $ friday     : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ saturday   : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ independent: int  2249 2381 4185 2899 2387 2145 2933 2617 2378 3569 ...
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information! Thanks for the help guys (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no signal between target and indepedent. Ignoring weekday for now, if you fit the linear model with and without gradient:

```
# a linear model looking at response with indepedent (with intercept)
lm1 <- lm(target ~ indepedent, data = training)
lm1
#
# Call:
# lm(formula = target ~ indepedent, data = training)
#
# Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)    indepedent  
# 206.37312594    0.04853823 
# intercept only
lm0 <- lm(target ~ 1, data = training)
lm0
#
# Call:
# lm(formula = target ~ 1, data = training)
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  
#   310.0769  
# two models of the data equivalent to possible outcomes
plot(target ~ indepedent, data = training)
lines(fitted(lm1) ~ indepedent, data = training, lty = 2)
lines(fitted(lm0) ~ indepedent, data = training, col = 2)
```

... the intercept only model is preferred:

```
# test which model is better
# large p-value suggests we're happy accepting the simple model
anova(lm0, lm1)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#
# Model 1: target ~ 1
# Model 2: target ~ indepedent
#   Res.Df       RSS Df  Sum of Sq       F  Pr(>F)
# 1     12 86990.923                             
# 2     11 81792.165  1 5198.7582 0.69917 0.42086
head(fitted(lm0))
#         428         429         430         431         432         433 
# 310.0769231 310.0769231 310.0769231 310.0769231 310.0769231 310.0769231
```

So this is what the machine learning approach is also telling you. The simple model predicts a single value for target for every value of indepedent. Adding in the weekday variable apparently does not improve this.

You saw predictions for your toy example because there was a strong signal in the response.

Comment: When I add more covariates, could it be possible that the neural network will work (in other words: my only problem is that the current set of covariates does not have any explanatory power concerning the target)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that covariates exist that explain the relationship between target and indepedent, except that you are not including them. If you have any mechanistic understanding of how these variables are related, that might suggest a variable to try. If you just hope there is a relationship then try lots of variables; once you've got a candidate explanatory variable, see whether that holds true in your test data. Try to finish exploration of your training data before looking at the test!